# How recursion calls are working in the call stacks

Tags: python

Here is a code that works for generating all the well-form parenthesis combinations by getting an integer as the number of open/close parentheses using recursive calls.

```
class Solution:
    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int):
        res = []
        
        def backtrack(open_count, close_count, combination):
            if open_count == close_count == n:
                res.append(combination)
                return

            if open_count < n:
                backtrack(open_count + 1, close_count, combination + "(")

            if close_count < open_count:
                backtrack(open_count, close_count + 1, combination + ")")
                
        backtrack(0, 0, "")
        
        return res

sol = Solution()
result = sol.generateParenthesis(3)
```

I am bit perplexed why/how after forming the first combination which is `'((()))'` next combination will be formed.

In my debugger after the case where `open_count=close_count=3`, it jumps to the case where `close_counts=1` and `open_counts=2` and continues to check the if statements hereafter. I am still wondering why it jumped to this case to form the next combination.

Comment: Each recursive call has its own `open_count` and `close_count` variables. When you return from `open_count=close_count=3` those variables revert to their values from before the call.

Comment: To understand this, write down the variables and their values on paper. When you make a recursive call, stack another piece of paper on top; when you return from the call, throw away that piece.

Comment: You can [visualize your code](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display), step by step.